# Looking for a way to determine why a packet leaving my cluster would keep it's pod IP

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a network issue on my cluster and at first I thought it was a routing issue but discovered that maybe the outgoing packet from the cluster isn't getting wrapped with the node ip when leaving the node.

Background is that I have two clusters.  I set up the first one (months ago) manually using [this guide](https://cloud-provider-vsphere.sigs.k8s.io/tutorials/kubernetes-on-vsphere-with-kubeadm.html) and it worked great.  Then the second one I built multiple times as I created/debugged anisble scripts to automate how I created the first cluster.

On cluster2 I have the network issue...  I can get to pods on other nodes but can't get to anything on my regular network.  I have tcpdump'd the physical interface on node0 in cluster2 when pinging from a busybox pod and the 172.16.0.x internal pod ip is visible at that interface as the source ip - and my network outside the node has no idea what to do with it.  But on cluster1 this same test shows the node ip in place of the pod ip - which is how I assume it should work.

My question is how can I troubleshoot this?  Any ideas would be great as I have been at this for several days now.  Even if it seems obvious as I can no longer see the forest through the trees... ie.  both clusters look the same everywhere I know how to check :)

caveat to "my clusters are the same": Cluster1 is running kubectl 1.16 cluster2 is running 1.18

----edit after @Matt dropped some kube-proxy knowledge on me----

Did not know that kube-proxy rules could just be read by iptables command! Awesome!

I think my problem is those 10.net addresses in the broke cluster. I don't even know where those came from as they are not in any of my ansible config scripts or kube init files...  I use all 172's in my configs.

I do pull some configs direct from source (flannel and CSI/CPI stuff) I'll pull those down and inspect them to see if the 10's are in there... Hopefully it's in the flannel defaults or something and I can just change that yml file!

cluster1 working:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# iptables -t nat -vnL| grep POSTROUTING -A5
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 1346 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
6743K  550M KUBE-POSTROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes postrouting rules */
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
3383K  212M RETURN     all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/16        172.16.0.0/16
 117K 9002K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/16       !224.0.0.0/4
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *      !172.16.0.0/16        172.16.0.0/24
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *      !172.16.0.0/16        172.16.0.0/16
```

cluster2 - not working:

```
[root@testvm-master ~]# iptables -t nat -vnL | grep POSTROUTING -A5
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1152 packets, 58573 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 719K   37M KUBE-POSTROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes postrouting rules */
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       10.244.0.0/16        10.244.0.0/16
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.244.0.0/16       !224.0.0.0/4
 131K 7849K RETURN     all  --  *      *      !10.244.0.0/16        172.16.0.0/24
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *      !10.244.0.0/16        10.244.0.0/16
```

Comment: What CNI plugin are you using? Kubernetes does not require NAT as the only rules for CNI are about pod to pod comms. You are entirely allowed to assign a public routable IP to every pod if you wanted.

Comment: The will be an outgoing source or masquerade NAT rule missing. Maybe lost it over a reboot?

Comment: @coderanger i'm using Flannel.

Comment: @Matt Where might I find that? From what I understand kube-proxy is just iptables in disguise but I don' t really know how to see it - is that what conntrack shows me? Hasn't been a reboot since my most recent creation of the cluster.

Comment: `iptables -t nat -vnL` will list everything. If you add `POSTROUTING` or `KUBE-POSTROUTING` you will get the specific chains most likely to house the rules.

Comment: It's usually something flannel or calico would set up.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the iptables clue!  I had no idea I could use that to see what kube-proxy was doing! Very handy.

Comment: Cool. The main thing to realise about containers is they are all linux primitives underneath. The runtimes and software built on top mostly lets you wrangle them more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boom! @Matt advice for the win.

Using iptables to verify the nat rules that flannel was applying did the trick.  I was able to find the 10.244 subnet in the flannel config that was referenced in the guide I was using.

I had two options.
1. download and alter the flannel yaml before deploying the CNI
or
2. make my kubeadmin init subnet declaration match what flannel has.

I went with option 2 because I don't want to alter the flannel config everytime...  I just want to pull down their latest file and run with it.  This worked quite nicely to resolve my issue.